# Draw a Square on the HTML5 Canvas With Touch Events

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, touch

I have a problem, I'm trying to draw a square on the canvas with the use of touch event and it not working, can someone help me figure out why?

---

Here's my code so far:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// "Draw Rectangle" Button
function rect(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasSignature'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), rect = {}, drag = false;

function init() {
  canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, false);
  canvas.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, false);
}


function touchHandler(event) {
  if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) { //one finger touche
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];

    if (event.type == "touchstart") {
      rect.startX = touch.pageX;
      rect.startY = touch.pageY;
      drag = true;
    } else if (event.type == "touchmove") {
      if (drag) {
        rect.w = touch.pageX - rect.startX;
        rect.h = touch.pageY - rect.startY ;
        draw();
      }
    } else if (event.type == "touchend" || event.type == "touchcancel") {
      drag = false;
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}

init();
}
```

---

HTML5:

```
      <div id="canvasDiv">
    <canvas id="canvasSignature" width="580px" height="788px" style="border:2px solid #000; background: #FFF;"></canvas>
</div>



<div id="rect">  
    <p><button onclick="rect();">Rectangle</button></p>
</div>
```

---

Thanks again,
Wardenclyffe

Comment: What device(s) are you testing this on?

Comment: I've been testing it on my iPhone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in Chrome with emulated touch events works with this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/A4R82/) The problem seems to be the way you bind your click event. I just used jQuery.

Or without jQuery: [just a plain addEventListener](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/A4R82/2/)

Comment: So how exactly could I fix it? I'm not sure I get it. I tried it on jsFiddle before to and it wouldn't run.